# What is the setting to do "After Test Suite"

Tags: robotframework

I try to find a way to execute a keyword after the test suite. Something like `Suite Setup` for after the execution.

There is a way to do that?

Comment: This is mentioned in the robot user guide, in a section titled [Suite Setup & Teardown](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#suite-setup-and-teardown)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Suite Teardown` defined in the Settings section - it will be the last thing ran for the suite, after the last case's teardown.

It is explained in details in the user guide - http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#suite-setup-and-teardown

Comment: Thank you but it is done on the Test. Not on the Test Suite correct?